# Overlays To Hide for Certain Period of Time When User Clicks Close Button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Seeking help in finding good tutorials and readings on to set up an overlay like this:

when someone clicks the close button, do not show the overlay again until 15 days or some time period in the code.

I assume this would be saving a cookie, just trying to find good articles on the subject. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i'm just trying to find what the term is called, i can do all the legwork. i also accept all answers i am not sure why it keeps saying that low rating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this using the jQuery Cookie plugin:
[jQuery Cookie Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie)

Fire this on the callback from the closing function.

```
$.cookie("mysiteOverlayIsClosed", "true", { expires: 15 });
```

Then, to check if the user has that cookie or not, you can just call something like this.

```
if($.cookie("mysiteOverlayIsClosed")){
   //Code To not show popup
}else{
   //Code to fire popup
}
```

Something like this should work, though it may not be the most efficient. 
Good Luck

Comment: Js - the $.cookie() is a jquery function